# Exclude values from Random.Range()?

Tags: c#, random, unity-game-engine

If you are using `Random.Range()` to generate values, is there any way to exclude some values within the range (for example: pick a number between 1 and 20, but not 6 through 8)?

Comment: You can write your own method to check if generated number falls into excluded ranges and in this case re-generate it.

Comment: I've added the random tag to introduce this question to the many random number experts on this site, and to give my answer some credibility.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use your favourite generator to generate an integer `n` between 1 and 17 then transform using

```
if (n > 5){
    n += 3;
}
```

If you sample between 1 and 20 then discard values you can introduce statistical anomalies, particularly with low discrepancy sequences.

Answer (score 10):

So you actually want `17` (20 - 3) different values

```
  [1..5] U [9..20]
```

and you can implement something like this:

```
  // Simplest, not thread-safe
  private static Random random = new Random();

  ...  

  int r = (r = random.Next(1, 17)) > 5
    ? r + 3
    : r;
```

In general (and complicated) case I suggest generating an array of all possible values and then take
the item from it:

```
  int[] values = Enumerable
    .Range(1, 100) // [1..100], but
    .Where(item => item % 2 == 1) // Odd values only
    .Where(item => !(item >= 5 && item <= 15)) // with [5..15] range excluded
    //TODO: Add as many conditions via .Where(item => ...) as you want
    .ToArray();

  ...

  int r = values[random.Next(values.Length)];
```

Comment: Plus one, this is statistically correct; I'm trusting that the assignment on the conditional test to a variable you've defined on the left of the assignment is well-defined in C#!

Comment: Unity3D provides a Random class and most users rely on that one. Also, Linq is not so recommended in Unity for internal reason (FullAOT on iOS) which makes some of its functionalities not always work.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, You simple use `where` statment in LINQ

```
   var list = Enumerable.Range(1, 20).Where(a => a < 6 || a > 8).ToArray();
```

Other way witout LINQ

```
        public IEnumerable RangeBetween()
        {
            foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(1, 20))
            {
                if (i < 6 || i > 8)
                {
                    yield return i;
                }
            }
        }
```

EDIT: Now I see is not a strict C# question . It affect `Unity` and `Random`. But for complete answer I sugest You use code above with  `Enumerable.Range` and next use this for generate the number:

```
list[Random.Next(list.Length)];
```

Comment: This is for game engine. If you can avoid linq, avoid it. It allocates memory and some functions wont work in iOS.

Comment: @Programmer Avoid  lambda expression too?

Comment: I wouldn't say that. I mean if he calling that code  most of the time, he should avoid it.

Comment: @Programmer LINQ works fine on iOS if you use Lists instead of arrays. It is a great asset for abstracting the complications of loops and lists. I think the reason why it works only with Lists on iOS because LINQ doesn't use `IEnumerable` (which has problems on iOS) on Lists whereas on arrays it does. Interesting.

Comment: @MyIsaak Yes it works with List. It's not working because of AOT features not available on iOS. Although I use few linq functions from it only when **necessary**. Still, the first code in his answer will still allocate memory just to generate random number....Not worth the sacrifice.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to make an array of the valid return values and then randomly select one:

```
void Main()
{
    var rng = new Random();
    var validValues = Enumerable.Range(1, 20).Except(new int[] {6, 7, 8}).ToArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        Console.Write(validValues[rng.Next(0, validValues.Length)]);
        Console.Write(" ");
    }
}
```

EDIT:  Oops!  Just noticed this was for Unity3D so this example might not be appropriate.  It works using the standard  `Random` class, though.

Answer (score 0):

This will pick a different random number if r is in the range 6-8 inclusive.

```
int r = 0;
do
{
    r = Random.Next(20);
} while (r >= 6 && r <= 8)
```

Comment: I think that using this method there is a chance (really small one, but still) that the program enters in an infinite loop... if you always get a number between 6 and 8.

Comment: I feel like commenting on this one. This is a great way to  freeze your game. @Ignacio You are right. This has happened to me before. No while loop while generating random number in Unity.

Comment: @Programmer, not just in Unity, It can freeze any program

Comment: @Ignacio Good to know that.

Comment: Uh, it really can't freeze a program. Computers rely on being able to generate random numbers and use random processes everywhere - things like the internet and its protocols rely on that - there is a chance that a packet will drop and never arrive but statistically this never happens. If you run this program on a computer since the start of the universe until now it would not ever get stuck - it's easy to prove that on a uniform probability (or any probability with a non-zero chance for a number not between 6 and 8 to appear) that it would likely not get stuck for over a second ever.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I have made the following serializable class:

```
[Serializable]
public class cRandom
{
    private int IntResult = 0;
    private List<int> Possibilities;
    private int IntCheckCount = 0;
    private int IntCheckCurrent = 0;
    private int ExceptionCurrent = 0;
    private int ExceptionCount = 0;
    private bool isException = false;
    public int Range_Int_WithException(int min, int max, int exception)
    {
        Possibilities = new List<int>();
        IntCheckCount = max - min;
        if(IntCheckCount <= 1)
        {
            //If the random range only include 2 possibilities and one is the exception.
            //If there's no possible result, return the minimum value.
            if(exception == min)
            {
                IntResult = max;
            }
            else
            {
                IntResult = min;
            }
            return IntResult;
        }
        else
        {
            for (IntCheckCurrent = min; IntCheckCurrent < max; IntCheckCurrent++)
            {
                if (IntCheckCurrent != exception)
                {
                    Possibilities.Add(IntCheckCurrent);
                }
            }
            IntResult = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, IntCheckCount);
            return Possibilities[IntResult];
        }
    }
    public int Range_Int_WithExceptions(int min, int max, int[] exceptions)
    {
        Possibilities = new List<int>();
        ExceptionCount = exceptions.Length;
        for (IntCheckCurrent = min; IntCheckCurrent < max; IntCheckCurrent++)
        {
            isException = false;
            for (ExceptionCurrent = 0; ExceptionCurrent < ExceptionCount; ExceptionCurrent++)
            {
                if (IntCheckCurrent == exceptions[ExceptionCurrent])
                {
                    isException = true;
                }
            }
            if (!isException)
            {
                Possibilities.Add(IntCheckCurrent);
            }
        }
        IntCheckCount = Possibilities.Count;
        if(IntCheckCount <= 0)
        {
            //There's no possible solution. Return minimum by default;
            return min;
        }
        else
        {
            IntResult = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, IntCheckCount);
            return Possibilities[IntResult];
        }
    }

    private float result = 0f;
    private float Possible_Minimum = 0f;
    private float Possible_Maximum = 0f;
    public float Range_Float_WithException(float min, float max, float exception, float precision, bool Rounded)
    {
        //Just making sure that the min is lower than the max value.
        if(max >= min)
        {
            Possible_Minimum = min;
            Possible_Maximum = max;
        }
        else
        {
            Possible_Maximum = min;
            Possible_Minimum = max;
        }
        //minimum is within the exception's precision range. Raise the minimum outside of the exception range.
        if (Possible_Minimum <= exception + precision && Possible_Minimum >= exception - precision)
        {
            Possible_Minimum = exception + precision;
        }
        if (Possible_Maximum <= exception + precision && Possible_Maximum >= exception - precision)
        {
            Possible_Maximum = exception - precision;
        }
        if (Possible_Maximum < Possible_Minimum)
        {
            //The range between min and max is to small from the exception precision range.
            //return by default the minimum value.
            result = min;
        }
        else
        {
            result = UnityEngine.Random.Range(Possible_Minimum, Possible_Maximum);
            //Check if result is within the exception precision range
            if(result >= exception - precision && result <= exception + precision)
            {
                if(result <= exception)
                {
                    if (Rounded)
                    {
                        result = (float)Mathf.FloorToInt(UnityEngine.Random.Range(Possible_Minimum, exception - precision));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result = UnityEngine.Random.Range(Possible_Minimum, exception - precision);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (Rounded)
                    {
                        result = (float)Mathf.CeilToInt(UnityEngine.Random.Range(exception + precision, Possible_Maximum));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result = UnityEngine.Random.Range(exception + precision, Possible_Maximum);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (Rounded)
                {
                    result = (float)Mathf.RoundToInt(result);
                    //Check if the rounded value is too close to the exception range.
                    if(result >= exception - precision && result <= exception + precision)
                    {
                        if (result <= exception)
                        {
                            result -= 1f;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            result += 1f;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

I added the class and a static instance of the class in my GameMaster.cs script which is the script that is set with DontDestroyOnLoad() and which every scene in my game refers to when it comes to stuff like saved values (like accessing the values in the options and player saves), scene changes, etc.

*public static cRandom CustomRandom { get; set; }*

When I initiated the game, I do a bunch of stuff in that GameMaster script like loading the option file data and, on first launch, generating the folders for the save files, etc. I included a simple:

*CustomRandom = new cRandom();*

to that particular function which loads up the stuff on launch. Then all I got to do is call that function with, in my case, *GameMaster.CustomRandom.Range_xxxxxx()* and fill out the relevant minimum, maximum and exception(s).

You might not need the Random Float, but I think it's a neat option when you need an random float value, but want to avoid a specific range within the possibilities. It's also a way to avoid issues with issues with floats precision when converted internally (like with Vectors values).

For example, if you use
GameMaster.CustomRandom.Range_Float_WithException(0f, 1f, 0.5f, 0.01f, false);
The function will return a value between 0f and 0.49f or between 0.51f and 1f.

The quality of this method is that it is Garbage Collector friendly so that even if you call it millions of times, the amount of memory reserved for the function remains extremely low because you're basically re-using the same blocks of memory to calculate various results instead of generating new ones.

The only CON of this method is that you have to watch out for the rare moments where your game call it anywhere outside of the regular frame order. For example, calling it from a coroutine can result in unwanted results since a coroutine can hang onto the function for more than 1 frame and another call of the function during that extensive hanging could overwrite the result stored in the memory before the coroutine ends its reading of it. If you got some function (like in a coroutine) that make heavy uses of this, you should just use a separate instance of the class in a separate script, like in the script that manage the coroutine. (At worse, you could just generate in said coroutine when it's started.)

The "Rounded" boolean for the Random float is in case you need a fixed whole value as a float. (Like if you want to set the value on a UI Slider with the "*Whole Numbers*" checked or if you want to select a precise float value for an animation.) I incorporated the optional rounding within the function because doing it outside of it could fall within the exception's range.

Setting the Float precision to an extremely low float value is inadvisable unless the result really require that kind of precision.

I didn't made a version of the float with multiple exceptions as I didn't needed it yet, but I could see its use. It's kinda of a pinball process, but it's doable with the example for integer, but adapted with the example for floats.

Answer (score -1):

I'm going to throw in my 2 cents on the subject. Here is a complete class showing a method that generates a random number excluding numbers of your choice  and how to use it.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class test2 : MonoBehaviour {

    System.Random rand;
    int[] excludelist;
    void Start()
    {
         rand = new System.Random();
        excludelist = new int[] { 5,9,3};
        for(int i = 0; i<20;i++)
        {
            Debug.Log(MakeMeNumber(excludelist));
        }

    }
    private int MakeMeNumber(params int[] excludeList)
    {
        var excluding = new HashSet<int>(excludeList);
        var range = Enumerable.Range(1, 20).Where(i => !excluding.Contains(i));


        int index = rand.Next(0, 20 - excluding.Count);
        return range.ElementAt(index);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I've created an asset designed exactly for that case (it's paid).

It simply contains a few useful functions that generate a random number from the given intervals (between X and Y excluding Z, for example).

Your example (between 1 and 20, but excluding 6 to 8) would be covered by the third function, RandomExclude.RandomInt (int, int, Vector2). The first int is the lowest possible value, the second int is the highest and the Vector2 is the interval that we exclude. In your case it'd look like that:

int ourOutcome = RandomExclude.RandomInt (1, 20, new Vector2 (6, 8));

The asset contains a few more similar functions, they let you generate an int excluding one number, excluding a few numbers or excluding a few intervals.

All detailed instructions of implementation are already covered in the asset itself, so don't worry.

[https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/input-management/random-exclude-133786](http://Hey!%20%20I've%20created%20an%20asset%20designed%20exactly%20for%20that%20case%20(it's%20paid).%20%20https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/input-management/random-exclude-133786%20%20Feel%20free%20to%20try%20it!)

Feel free to try it!